# Calculating percentage of random numbers

Tags: java

So,

I am trying to generate random number between 0 and 50. I have several question from here. After generation, I want to calculate the range of generated numbers between [0,25] and [25,50]. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Random1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Generating 10 random numbers between 21 - 40");

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        int randomInt;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {

            int Low = 0;
            int High = 50;
            int Result;

            randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;

            System.out.println("Generated: " + randomInt);

        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in this code I generated 10 numbers between [0,50]

1st Question is:

How can I order them? For example: Generated numbers will be in ascending order.

2nd Question: From here, how can I get the generated numbers between [0,25] and [25, 50]. Should I use nested for ?

Thank you.

Comment: How to order integers: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-int-int-  Numbers between a range: an `if-else` will help you.

Comment: I need a range of it. How can I know  how many numbers generated between 0-25 with if else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say: create two Arraylists, name if something like arrayListRange1, arrayListRange2. Create an if condition and if the number generated is less than or qual to 25 then add it to arrayListRange1, if number is above 25 and less than or equal to 50 then add to arrayListRange2. To get them in order just create a new arraylist and add both lists to the new array, arrayListAllInOrder and then use sort to sort them in order.